# Plot differential equation system in a complex way

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Based on this differential equation system:

$$\begin{align*}
\dot{x}&=f(x,y)\\
\dot{y}&=g(x,y)
\end{align*}$$

where

$$\begin{align*}
f(x, y)&=x^2+y^2-25\\
g(x, y)&=x^2-y^2-7
\end{align*}$$

I have to show how these two differential equations (I've named them `xdot` and `ydot`) when they are equal $0$. I have to show with arrow symbols like on this picture:

[image: the correct painting]

The closest to the picture is this plot with lane curves. However I must show it with arrows like i have on the picture. Is this possible in Mathematica, if yes, how?

```
Clear[x, y, xdot, ydot, curves, zerocurves, specielarrows]
xdot = x^2 + y^2 - 25;
ydot = x^2 - y^2 - 7;
xmin = -6;
xmax = 6;
ymin = -6;
ymax = 6;
curves = 30;
specielarrows = {{{6, 0}, Directive[Orange, Thick]}};
{Append[specielarrows, curves]};

(* plots *)
zerocurves = 
 ContourPlot[{xdot == 0, ydot == 0}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
  ContourStyle -> {Directive[Red, Thick], Directive[Blue, Thick]}, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]       

lanecurves = 
 VectorPlot[{xdot, ydot}, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
  StreamPoints -> {Append[specielarrows, curves]}, 
  StreamStyle -> Green, VectorStyle -> Black, Axes -> True, 
  Frame -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]

Show[zerocurves, lanecurves]
```

Comment: Differential equations?

Comment: Yes. The lanes show which points are asymptotic stable and unstable of the differential equation system. 
Do you think it is a wrong tag??

Comment: No I meant that `xdot` and `ydot` are not differential equations but now I understand that those are the rhs of $\dot x$ and $\dot y$.

Comment: The points that the two curves intersect are the equilibrium points of the system. Put what about the vectors? they seem to be positioned in a random fashion.

Comment: @Spawn1701D I have added the differential equation system in the text so it should be more clear.
Yes, the vectors are positioned in a random fashion.

Comment: And they denote the vector $(f(x,y),g(x,y))$ at that point?

Comment: @Spawn1701D I am not quite sure if I understand your question..

Comment: I think I get it they just denote the direction of the flow of your dynamic system.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Okay, i understand your question now. Yes they show the flow of the dynamic system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok first of all lets define $f,g$:

```
f[x_, y_] = xdot
g[x_, y_] = ydot
```

next we define our two kind of arrows:

```
scale = 2 (* this determines how long the arrow will be*)

blueArrow[x_, y_,s:(-1 | 1)] := {
    Arrowheads[{{Large, Automatic,
    Graphics[Line[{{{-1/3, 1/6}, {0, 0}, {-1/3, -1/6}}}]]}}], 
    RGBColor[98/255, 150/255, 199/255], AbsoluteThickness[3], 
    Arrow[{{x, y}, {x, y + scale*s}}]
 }

redArrow[x_, y_, s : (-1 | 1)] := {
    Arrowheads[{{Large, Automatic, 
    Graphics[Line[{{{-1/2, 1/4}, {0, 0}, {-1/2, -1/4}}}]]}}], 
    RGBColor[203/255, 103/255, 98/255], AbsoluteThickness[3], 
    Arrow[{{x, y}, {x + scale*s, y}}]
}
```

with the next commands we get randomly n points

```
testPoints[n_Integer] := {RandomInteger[{1, 3}], #}&/@Thread[{RandomReal[{xmin+scale/2, 
                                                                         xmax-scale/2}, n], 
                         RandomReal[{ymin+scale/2, ymax-scale/2}, n]}]
```

then we find the arrows at those points:

```
testArrows =   Switch[#1, 
                      1 (* only the horizontal *), redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 
                      2(* only the vertical *), blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g @@ #2]], 
                      3(* both *), {redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 
                                    blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g@@#2]]}]&@@@testPoints[10];
```

Now we are ready to plot the final image

```
Show[zerocurves, testArrows // Graphics, PlotRange->All]
```

> [image: final pic]

Note: because of the fact that the points are chosen randomly things mught not look nice, You can instead give your own list of points in place of `testPoints[n]`. The syntax is `{{1|2|3,{x,y}}..}` where when 1 you plot only the horizontal arrow, 2 the vertical and 3 both.

---

Just for fun:

```
 Manipulate[Show[zerocurves, Graphics[Switch[#1, 1 (*only the horizontal*), 
  redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 2(*only the vertical*),
   blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g @@ #2]], 
  3(*both*), {redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 
   blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g @@ #2]]}] & @@@ {{3, 
  p}}]], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

> [image: Interactive pic]

```
Manipulate[Show[zerocurves, Graphics[Switch[#1, 1 (*only the horizontal*), 
  redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 2(*only the vertical*),
   blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g @@ #2]], 
  3(*both*), {redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 
   blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g @@ #2]]}] & @@@ {{m, 
  p}}]], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}, {{m, 3, ""}, {1 -> "horizontal",2 -> "vertical", 
  3 -> "both"}}]
```

> [image: iPic 2]

Finally, with this one you click and create a new point:

```
  Manipulate[pic[m, p], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator}, {{m, 3, ""}, {1 -> "horizontal", 
  2 -> "vertical", 3 -> "both"}}, Initialization :> {points = {}; 
  pic[m_, p_] :=  Module[{}, AppendTo[points, {m, p}]; Show[zerocurves, 
  Graphics[
   Switch[#1, 1 (*only the horizontal*), 
      redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 
      2(*only the vertical*), 
      blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g @@ #2]], 
      3(*both*), {redArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[f @@ #2]], 
       blueArrow[Sequence @@ #2, Sign[g @@ #2]]}] & @@@ 
    points]]]}]
```

> [image]

Comment: Nice answer! I would recommend not to indent your code that much. An indentation of 2 spaces is really enough. The important advantage is, that you can make your code so narrow, that you don't get the horizontal scrollbars underneath the blocks.

Comment: I get the arrows, and they have the correct pointing. However, I wonder why my image turn red, as if there is a fault. What might this cause?

Comment: Yes I was trying to keep also a "visual grouping".

Comment: @JensJensen let me see for any typo

Comment: @JensJensen the function `testPoints` needs `:=` instead of `=`.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Yes, I've seen your grouping. I re-formatted your first code-block to be smaller and still have the grouping. If you really don't like it, just revert to the previous editing-version.

Comment: @Spawn1701D It doesn't help it. I have just copied your code into a document. 
I cannot add all the code because it has too many characters. 
Do you want me to add multiple comments with the codes?

Comment: @Spawn1701D it says:
"Switch is not a Graphics primitive or directive."

Comment: Is it maybe because I have mma 8?

Comment: @JensJensen did you correct the function `testPoints `?

Comment: @JensJensen no I have the same version. try quitting the kernel and run the commands from the start.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Yes I did.

Comment: @Spawn1701D It still doesn't work. Can I somehow email you my document, or let you review it in another way?

Comment: @JensJensen yes send it to spawn@math.upatras.gr

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8415/discussion-between-jens-jensen-and-spawn1701d)

Comment: @halirutan no problem, thanx for your time!